# Getting "At least one sheet must be visible" when trying to open excel spreadsheet. What to do?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

When trying to open an excel spreadsheet do same changes and save it:

```py
import openpyxl

workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename = 'sample.xlsx', read_only=False)
workbook.save('test.xlsx')
```

I get the following upon calling `save()`:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read_pyxl.py", line 4, in <module>
    workbook.save('test.xlsx')
  File "/home/martin/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/workbook.py", line 407, in save
    save_workbook(self, filename)
  File "/home/martin/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 293, in save_workbook
    writer.save()
  File "/home/martin/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 275, in save
    self.write_data()
  File "/home/martin/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/writer/excel.py", line 89, in write_data
    archive.writestr(ARC_WORKBOOK, writer.write())
  File "/home/martin/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/_writer.py", line 148, in write
    self.write_views()
  File "/home/martin/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/_writer.py", line 135, in write_views
    active = get_active_sheet(self.wb)
  File "/home/martin/myvenv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/openpyxl/workbook/_writer.py", line 33, in get_active_sheet
    raise IndexError("At least one sheet must be visible")
IndexError: At least one sheet must be visible
>>>
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: The error message also acts as a catch-all error. With this in mind, check to see that there are no issues with any of the dataframes you are trying to write into a sheet. I noticed my dataframe itself returned an error. Once I debugged my dataframe, my excel file was able to be written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out in this case `sample.xlsx` had all sheets set to "hidden".
If at least **one** of the sheets is set to be visible the code works.

A weird limitation, but it exists.

Comment: I have a similar issue, do you know how to fix the issue from the code?